# Security Assembly Declaration does nothing?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am trying to restrict the permissions my assembly has using Security Declarations. I have the follow example:

```
 [assembly: UIPermission(SecurityAction.RequestOptional,Unrestricted = true)]
[assembly: FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.RequestOptional, Read = @"C:\Hello.txt")]
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a file
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Hello.txt");
        tw.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        tw.Close();

        // Display the text of the file
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Hello.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
        tr.Close();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The second line in the main() is writing to the file that explicitly set to 'read only' permissions (at least I thought). Running this example does not result in a security exception thrown. Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your app is running with full-trust. In full trust granular CAS permissions *are not checked*.

Comment: I believe you must be right. I must have done this in win 7 security settings. I didn't change the code group policy specifically. Meaning.. I didn't do this using using the CAS Management tool.